# configure firewalld to allow trafic from docker0 to enp7s0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, firewalld, almalinux

I am using an AlmaLinux and using firewalld as the firewall in my server. But I am unable to access other services which are bound by another network interface (enp7s0). by the way I am able access internet within the docker (thanks to [this](https://dev.to/soerenmetje/how-to-secure-a-docker-host-using-firewalld-2joo) guide).

```bash
docker network create --driver bridge mynet
docker run --rm --net mynet alpine sh -c 'apk add curl && curl 10.0.0.2:8080/metrics'
```

curl is getting installed (we have the internet access from within the container), but the `curl 10.0.0.2:8080/metrics` is failed.

I am accessing public internet through `eth0` interface and there is another network interface (`enp7s0`) which is having the IP `10.0.0.2`

How do I configure firewalld to allow the traffic from docker0 to enp7s0?